# How to define a inbound security rule in a NSG defining source as an Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, azure-nsg

There is an Azure VM with an Oracle DB installed. I need to access that DB using port 1521 from an SSIS package running on an Azure data factory SSIS runtime. The relevant SSIS DB is in an Azure SQL Server.

For the time being my nsg rule defined as below.

- Source - Any
- Source port range - *
- Destination - IP Addresses
- Dest IP - Private IP of the Azure VM with Oracle
- Service - Custom
- Dest Port - 1521
- Protocol - TCP

Since the source is defined as any there is a security risk associated with that.

I tried using

- Source - Service Tag
- Source Service Tag - DataFactory or sql.NorthEurope

and

- Source - IP address
- IP address - gateway IP range for North Europe

But all those give TNS timeout. Only the rule mentioned on top is working fine so far.

How can I define the source so that only the Azure SQL server or SSIS runtime will be able to access the Oracle DB on the VM?
It seems like the Azure SQL server only has a fully qualified DNS name (FQDN) [xyz.database.windows.net] but not a public IP associated with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below link.

It says when using SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) in Azure Data
Factory, you should join your Azure-SSIS integration runtime (IR) to
an Azure virtual network in the following scenarios:

- You want to connect to on-premises data stores from SSIS packages
  that run on your Azure-SSIS IR without configuring or managing a
  self-hosted IR as proxy.
- You want to host SSIS catalog database (SSISDB) in Azure SQL Database
  with IP firewall rules/virtual network service endpoints or in SQL
  Managed Instance with private endpoint.
- You want to connect to Azure resources configured with virtual
  network service endpoints from SSIS packages that run on your
  Azure-SSIS IR.
- You want to connect to data stores/resources configured with IP
  firewall rules from SSIS packages that run on your Azure-SSIS IR.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/join-azure-ssis-integration-runtime-virtual-network#access-to-data-sources-protected-by-ip-firewall-rule

Comment: This worked. Configured the SSIS IR with 2 public IPs and used them as Source IP Addresses in the NSG. @sav thank you